# Make Canvas Animation Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, css-animations

The following code is part of a bigger project:

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="check" width="35px" height="40px" style="background-color: blue;"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
  const check = document.getElementById('check');
  const checkCtx = check.getContext('2d');
  check.onclick = function() {
    drawCheck(checkCtx, 5, 30);
    setTimeout(function() {
      fadeOut(check);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      check.style.opacity = "1";
      checkCtx.clearRect(0, 0, check.width, check.height);
    }, 2000);
    check.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }

  function drawCheck(ctx, x, y) {
    var x1 = x;
    var y1 = y;
    var x2 = x1;
    var y2 = y1;
    var x3 = x1 + 14;
    var y3 = y1 + 7;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);

    function draw() {
      x2++;
      y2 += .5;
      ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
      ctx.stroke();
      if (x2 < x1 + 14) {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      } else {
        function drawNext() {
          x3 += .5;
          y3 -= 1.5;
          ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);
          ctx.stroke();
          if (x3 < x1 + 24) {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawNext);
          } else {
            return;
          }
        }
        drawNext();
        return;
      }
    }
    draw();
  }

  function fadeOut(obj) {
    var opc = 1;
    var finish = false;
    obj.style.opacity = 1;

    function fade() {
      opc -= 0.125;
      obj.style.opacity = opc + "";
      console.log(opc);
      if (opc > 0) {
        requestAnimationFrame(fade);
      }
    }
    console.log("Wait for it...");
    fade();
    console.log("Finished!");
  }
</script>
```

If you look at the console, you can see that the `fadeOut` function is ending before the `fade` function has ended. Because of this, I have to use multiple `setTimeout` functions. My other functions have the same problem. I don't want to have to rely on these, so how can I make the code wait until the called function has returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback (es5), promises(es6), async/await(es7)

You want to run code asynchronously. What that mean is wait for part code to finish job before run next one. Javascript by default doing everything as soon as it is possible , no mater what.

**Incorrect:**

```js
function run(){ 
  console.log('1: start run')
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('2: timeout')
  },1000)
}

function run2(){
  console.log('3: start run2')
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('4: timeout')
  },1000) // change time here and check order console.log's
}

function run3(){
  console.log('4: start run3')
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('5: timeout')
  },1000)
}
run()
run2()
run3()
```

3 functions are started in same time and they giving results without looking what is happening in other 2 functions. Try to change timeout to change order in conole.log. But in real life you don't have control over the time execution like here.

**Callback:**

With callback you are nesting one function in another passing it as a parameter. Idea is to wait for first function to execute before second one will start... wait for second one before third one... and so on.

```js
function runWithCallback(callback){ // run1
  console.log('1: start runWithCallback()')
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('2: timeout')
    callback(runAfterCallback)
  },1000)
}

function runCallback(callback){ // run2
  console.log("3: start runCallback()")
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('4: timeout')
    callback()
  },1000)
}

function runAfterCallback(){ // run3
  console.log("5: start runAfterCallback()")
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('6: timeout')
    // next call back here if needed
  },1000)
}

runWithCallback(runCallback)
```

Now no mater how long will by execution time of each function, next one will start after first one will finish. This way you don't need to guessing execution time to make delays in your code.

**Promises**

In es6 you can do it with promises what is kinda syntactic sugar over callback's. At the time of writing promises have a 90% browser coverage https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

```js
function run1(){
  console.log('1: run1')
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    console.log('2: promise')
    setTimeout(resolve,100)
  })
}

function callback(){
  console.log('3: run2 callback')
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    console.log('4: promise')
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
  })
}

function callback2(){
  console.log('5: run3 callback')
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    console.log('6: promise')
    setTimeout(resolve, 100)
  })
}

run1()
  .then(callback()) // try to change order here, uncoment last lines...
  .then(callback2())
  // .then(callback2())
  // .then(callback())
```